# Как сделать значение переменной объектом js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Есть функция ,возвращающая текст вида :

```json
{"location":{"name":"London","region":"City of London, Greater London","country":"United Kingdom","lat":51.52,"lon":-0.11,"tz_id":"Europe/London","localtime_epoch":1618235366,"localtime":"2021-04-12 14:49"},"current":{"condition":{},"uv":3.0},"forecast":{"forecastday":[{"date":"2021-04-12","date_epoch":1618185600,"day":{"condition":{"text":"Patchy rain possible","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png","code":1063}},"astro":{},"hour":[{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}}]},{"date":"2021-04-13","date_epoch":1618272000,"day":{"condition":{"text":"Overcast","icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/122.png","code":1009}},"astro":{},"hour":[{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}},{"condition":{}}]}]}}
```

как из этого текста сделать объект js и обращаться к полям объекта так obj.location.name или obj.forecast.forecastday ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Спасибо,вообще вылетело из головы парсирование